# How to strip square braces from string?

Tags: python, character, strip

I'm trying to strip a string containing []. Seems like it's not the case.

```
line = "This contains [Hundreds] of potatoes"
line = line.strip("[]")
print(line)
```

Actual results is the line, untouched.
How would I do this? Regex?

Comment: `str.strip` only removes leading or trailing characters, not arbitrarily in the center. If you just want to get rid of "[" and "]" you can use `str.replace`.

Comment: You may want to use the `replace` property of strings. You could also do `line.translate({91: '', 93:''})`. Note here that `ord('[')` is 91 and `ord(']')` is 93. Read up on the `translate` property

Comment: line.replace("[",'').replace("]","") without regex you will have to do it for each character. Its still usually faster to have multiple replace calls.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Remove the text bracketed by square brackets from the string?

Answer (score 2):

You can use regex for replacing the unwanted characters. Here's what you can do:

```
import re
line = "This contains [Hundreds] of potatoes"
line = re.sub(r"[\[\]]", "", line)
print(line)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is that you are using .strip when you should be using .replace
it works like this:

```
list = ("This contains [Hundreds] of potatoes")
list = list.replace("[" ,"")
list = list.replace("]" ,"")
print(list)
```

the first argument is what you want to replace and the second is what you are replacing by or with.
Hope this helps!

Comment: Why did you add parentheses around the string?

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: `list = ("...")` instead of just `list = "..."`

Comment: oh right, it's just habit I got taught that when I was in school :/

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `str.translate`:

## Python 2

```
>>> line.translate(None, '[]')
'This contains Hundreds of potatoes'
```

## Python 3

```
>>> line.translate(str.maketrans('', '','[]'))
'This contains Hundreds of potatoes'
```